# Как избавиться от рекурсии в запросе (сделать запрос без with recursive)

Tags: postgresql

Как избавиться от рекурсии в запросе:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION accounts.get_group_by_group(_id uuid)
RETURNS SETOF uuid AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN query
WITH RECURSIVE R AS 
(
 SELECT id
 FROM accounts.groups WHERE id=(_id)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT accounts.groups.id
 FROM accounts.groups
 JOIN R
 ON accounts.groups.parent_id = r.id
)
SELECT *FROM R;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Допустимо ли менять схему хранения дерева? Например, на штатный ltree? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html

Comment: Если более одного уровня вложенности в данных, то никак

Comment: а с помощью циклов как-то можно это организовать?схему хранения не планировали менять. в таблице есть id, parent_id,name

Comment: Циклом тоже можно. Но вернётесь к сущности рекурсивного решения. И смысл замены?

Comment: а можно посмотреть в виде кода?